# Can't remote debug Chromecast

Tags: chromecast, google-cast

I have a Chromecast (original) registered on my Cast developer console, but I can't debug any receivers. I've had it for a few years and used to be able to debug them remotely by visiting `*ip_of_chromecast*:9222`, but apparently that was removed in favor of `chrome://inspect`.

Unfortunately I can't get `chrome://inspect` to work. Here's what I see when casting either a Styled Media Receiver or a completely custom receiver:

[image: screenshot]

I'm pretty sure there's supposed to be a page I can inspect under the Chromecast, but there's never anything there. I've tried rebooting and doing a factory reset.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Fixed by unregistering and reregistering my Chromecast in the Cast Developer Console.